# Как правильно использовать position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Здравствуйте уважаемые,
Вопрос такого характера, который было сложно найти на просторах любимого,
есть div class = "box", есть макет, в котором есть блок, в нем изображение, а внутри изображения текст,
какой способ лучше? От товарища я узнал, что лучше делать слайдеры, или блоки img в блоке + position absolute, я использовал background: url(...) 0 0 / 100% no-repet; для слайдеров и прочих вещей, так как при использовании способа, текст легко поместить внутрь изображения просто создав блок, внутри блока, к которому через background добавлено изображение.
Сама суть: Я бы хотел узнать, как пользоваться position, я примерно знаю и понимаю, но даже если и текст появился внутри изображения, то ниже, там где он был, остается пространство, пустое, но все же не позволяющее подогнать следующие блоки в притык, расскажите пожалуйста как действовать, буду очень благодарен и многие другие люди, которые столкнуться в дальнейшем с этим :) спасибо за ранее!

Comment: тот случай, когда одна картинка была бы полезней 100 слов.

Comment: Хорошо дополню)

Comment: Хех, как бы сейчас смешно не казалось и нелепо, но пока я готовил тестовый блок, у меня все получилось и никаких проблем нет, которые мне по началу показалось есть, все равно спасибо, очень странно, но все сработало...

Comment: такое часто бывает, решение приходит в процессе подготовки вопроса